# Building NSDate from integers (year ... second) with Cocoa/objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

I have year, mont, ... , second in integer type, and I need to build NSDate from them.
I tried this code, but I got (null).

```
NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", year, month, day, hour, minute, second];
NSDate *day3 = [tempFormatter dateFromString:message];
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: What was the generates string in `message`? Did it look valid?  Paste that here as well.

Comment: "2011-03-14 20:14:40" is what is printout with NSLog(@"%@",message);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of

```
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

write

```
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Answer (score 34):

It would be more straightforward to create an `NSDateComponents` with your date components, and then use NSCalendar's `dateFromComponents:` to convert it to a date. [The documentation for NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has an example of how to do exactly this:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:day];
[comps setMonth:month];
[comps setYear:year];
[comps setHour:hour];
[comps setMinute:minute];
[comps setSecond:second];
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps release];
```

Comment: This is a much better way of doing it!  

The other way is effectively converting integer date "components" to a string, and from there to an NSDate! That's surely asking for trouble.

Comment: You can't use `NSGregorianCalendar`... it's deprecated, unfortunately. Completely remove the `NSCalendar *cal`'s initialization/release, and change `cal` in the creation of `date` to `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`. **You can no longer specify the Gregorian calendar.** Also, you can simplify the creation of `comps` by changing the line to this: `[NSDateComponents new];`

Comment: @DDPWNAGE: According to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626823/how-to-support-nscalendar-with-both-ios-7-and-8), it was basically just renamed to `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian`. Using `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` won't work right if the current calendar is one of the other supported calendars.