# How to support NSCalendar with both iOS 7 and 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

iOS 8 introduced some new values for old methods.
For instance, creating a calendar used to be like this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

Now, the calendar identifier has changed and I should create the object like so:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
```

Thing is, the compiler warns me only in the first situation that NSGregorianCalendar is deprecated. However, The compiler doesn't warn me at all about NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian compatibility with iOS 7.
**Does it mean that NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian works under iOS 7 either?**
If not, what's the best way of creating a calendar with a calendar identifier depending on the OS? checking OS version every single time seems tedious.
Thank you.

Comment: If you have a deployment target of iOS 7, then use `NSGregorianCalendar`. It will work just fine under both iOS 7 and iOS 8 and you will not get any deprecation warnings.

Comment: @rmaddy why don't put your comment in the answer?

Answer (score 31):

You can use the built-in `__IPHONE_8_0` macro, coupled with custom defines.

Your custom defines will simply refer to the underlying value defined in Objective-C. Since these are convenience defines that are widely used, I stick them into a header file, and include that in my PCH file (in Xcode 6, you have to create the pre-compiler header yourself, and point to it in your build settings).

When iOS 9 is released, you will still be able to use `__IPHONE_8_0` without updating, since it will still be defined, for all versions after iOS 8.

### In a header file (or Precompiler Header - project_name.pch)

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    #define GregorianCalendar NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian
#else
    #define GregorianCalendar NSGregorianCalendar
#endif
```

### In your implementation files

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:GregorianCalendar];
```

Comment: `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian  NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0)`. Why don't you use this `const` in both cases?

Comment: Using NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian with xCode 5 and compiled with iOS 7.1, yields this compiler error: `'NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian' is unavailable: not available on iOS`. With the defines in my answer, `GregorianCalendar` equates to 'gregorian' on both xCode 5 and 6. I think this is most useful when working with a team of developers, some of whom are still using xCode 5 for development.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that the const will still resolve to "gregorian" in future versions of the SDK?

Comment: To answer your question, @Gabriel, at this point it seems unlikely that these constants will be renamed anytime soon. However, if they are, __IPHONE_8_0 will still be defined, since it is guaranteed to be defined for all versions during and after iOS 8.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked about Gregorian specifically, but would it not always be preferable anyway to use:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
```

Comment: Sometimes you must use only `NSGregorianCalendar`, e.g. when use set `startDateComponents` and `dueDateComponents` for `EKReminder`